Beautiful Soup to scrape ebay, but data isn't lining up
I've been trying to scrape ebay. I've managed to find the right elements, use beautiful soup and create a df. However even though my code doesn't fail the data is clearly not right. For example even the the PrefLoc=1 in the url should point at UK listings, my df gets all US, australian listings etc. I seem to have a jumbled up df where price doesn't match shipping, that doesnt match product title etc. . Any help is much appreciated here!
def get_data(url): 
    r = requests. get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def parse_data(soup):
    product_list = []
    results = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 's-item__info clearfix'})
    for item in results[1:]: 
        # print(item)
        products = {
            'Product_Title': item.find('span', {'role': 'heading', 'aria-level': '3'}).text,
            'Price': float(item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__price'}).text.strip().replace('£', '').replace('$', '').replace(',', '')),
            'Shipping Cost': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__shipping s-item__logisticsCost'}).text,
            # 'Link': item.find('a', {'class': 's-item__link'})['href'],
            'Date Sold': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__caption--signal POSITIVE'}).text,
            'Location': item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__location'}).text.strip() if item.find('span', {'class': 's-item__location'}) else "UK",

        }
        product_list.append(products)
    return product_list



This is t data I am scraping: https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw="silver+tempest+booster+box"&_sacat=0&_sop=15&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&rt=nc&LH_PrefLoc=1

